# Create RDS Read-Replicate in a separate region using VPC

Tags: mysql-replication, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

We have a MySQL RDS instance in a VPC, and want to setup a read-replicata in another region.

Unfortunately since our RDS instance is in a VPC, we don't appear to have the option to replicate across regions.

The documentation isn't clear, but seems to hint that this should still be possible. Is there a way to do this? or is RDS cross-region replication only available for non-vpc instances?

Comment: Yes, you can do cross-region replicas with RDS for MySQL inside VPC.  (I  have them).  To create a read replica in another region, you connect to the *destination* region to [create the replica](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.XRgn), not the *source* region.  Please explain the point at which you aren't seeing what you expect to see.

Comment: Actually I think I found the issue - it appears Storage Encryption is the issue, not he VPC. Apparently it's not possible to do a read-replicate across regions for an encrypted RDS instance.